# Destroying an object that someone else has a reference to

Tags: c++

Suppose my application is using a library object `Server` which has a callback `onConnected`, which passes a reference to a `Connection` object when a new connection is established with a client; the `Server` retains ownership of the `Connection`. I would like to destroy the `Connection` when it is closed (whether locally or remotely), but I'm not sure how best to deal with notifying the application that is using the connection.

The obvious solution is to have some sort of `onDisconnected` callback and either `delete` it immediately, allowing the application to crash if it tries to continue using it, or pass it as `shared_ptr` and just let the object linger until the application cleans it up. Neither of these approaches feels particularly nice to me. The former just feels unsafe, and the latter muddies the concept of who owns the connection and makes leaks possible if the application ignores the callback.

Is there some idiomatic solution to this that I'm missing, or just a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear whether you're writing the library component or the application (or both), but if you don't own the object then it's not up to you to decide when to destroy it.

But look at how connection handles usually work in OS networking libraries; the application's connection handles don't suddenly become invalid when the connection closes. The application is the owner of its handle on the connection and is responsible for correctly closing it. But ultimately the actual data structures for dealing with the connection are owned by the kernel, and can be discarded when the connection is no longer actually open. Then the application will get well defined errors when trying to use the shut down connection.

Comment: I'm developing both. It's already in production, I'm just thinking of ways I can improve it. You make a good point about the way the OS does it. It's still kind of shared ownership, but perhaps a little better defined than just using a shared_ptr. I guess it's pretty much unavoidable.

Answer (score 5):

To me it seems that no-one is the clear owner of the object, so I'd go with using a `shared_ptr`. IMO it's exactly the kind of situation where you'd need it.